# How to export Reminders task to Todoist?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, reminders, todoist

Is there a way to export or synchronize Reminders tasks to Todoist?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible within the App itself.
Although you can download an App called [IFTTT](https://appsto.re/it/7BtzN.i), it connects the Apps you use and make them work together.

---

## Sync Reminders

When you connect two Apps in IFTTT you create a **Recipe**, turns out there's a recipe right for what you're looking for!
You can find one [here](https://ifttt.com/applets/222641p-use-siri-to-create-todoist-reminders) and [here](https://ifttt.com/applets/JQzAagNG-ios-reminder-todoist), after you've downloaded the IFTTT App.

Hope this helped you out!

Comment: Do you know if this way can synchronise the existing tasks or if it's only for new created tasks?

Comment: Mmmm I think it's for the existing ones, but I'll try right away and let you know @Kwadz

Comment: Mmmm turns out it's achievable using Siri asma a shortcut, so basically yes whenever you create a new reminder with Siri, or will be synced in your Todoist list. I think syncing your existing ones is impossible at the moment, if this cannot be achieved using a third-party app neither @Kwadz

Answer (score 0):

[Todoport](https://todoport.com/index.html) allows tasks migration between Wunderlist, Asana, Google Tasks, Toodledo, Trello, Todoist, and Apple Reminders.

However the app is not free, it costs $5 (for as many exports as you like).

Comment: This app doesn't exist anymore